# Pass object to has_many :conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to pass self as object not class to :conditions string, is there any way to do this?

```
has_many :topic,
:class => 'FileTopic',
:conditions => "id in (select * from file_topics where program_id = #{self.id})"
```

My problem is self is always giving me the id of the class but not the instance of the class. I guess has_many is evaluated on the class level?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is evalued upon loading the class, yeah. But only if you use double quotes - variables in single-quoted strings are filled upon calling. [More info here.](http://www.dweebd.com/ruby/has_many-with-arguments/)

However, maybe you should look into [named scopes](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/8/20/named-scope-it-s-not-just-for-conditions-ya-know)?

Answer (score 2):

Has many is a class method. So any reference to self in its arguments are references to the class.

It looks like you want to specify the foreign key on the belongs_to side of things.

Have you tried this yet:

```
has_many :topic, :class => 'FileTopic', :foreign_key => "program_id"
```

You should really have a read through the [ActiveRecord::Associations documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) if you haven't yet. There are very few association problems that can't be solved using the right set of options to belongs_to/has_one/has_many

Comment: the example i show here is way simpler than the actual thing. The association actually has UNION and some virtual tables in it.

Comment: As far as rails goes, UNIONs can be accomplished with polymorphic associations. There's probably a Rails Way to do virtual tables, without seeing what you're trying to achieve I can't advise. It's possible a :through relationship on a complex association, might work.